# How to fix error with .add, arrayList, and String array values in android?

Tags: android

In my Const.java I have

```
public static final String[] MONTHS = new String[]{<list of string values>}
public static final String[] YEARS = new String[]{<list of string values>}
public static int MONTH_NUM = <some int>;
public static int YEAR_NUM = <some int>;
```

in my other file i have

```
ArrayList<String> skList = new ArrayList<String>();
String month = Const.MONTHS[Const.MONTH_NUM];
String year = Const.YEARS[Const.YEAR_NUM];

skList.add(month);
skList.add(year);
```

then I got this error: ***The method add(String) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (String[])***

on lines:

```
skList.add(month);
skList.add(year);
```

Hope you can help. I already used all possible keywords I can come up w/ in Google.

Thanks.

Note: After I restarted eclipse and rebuild, several times, it ran.
thanks guys for all your comments.

Comment: Are you really doing `skList.add(month);` or `skList.add(MONTHS );` ?

Comment: skList.add(month); I'm adding a string.

Comment: Which line gives you the error ? `skList.add(month);` looks perfectly valid to me !

Comment: It doesn't look like the error occurs where you say it does. Post your stack trace and point us to the correct line number given by the thrown exception.

Comment: These lines:

skList.add(month);
skList.add(year);

Comment: I tried one more time (restarted eclipse and my machine).
then was ok.

I think it's an eclipse bug or something. Sorry guys for taking your time. And, thanks for helping.

Comment: @LexBryan Most likely something prevented Eclipse from rebuilding your project when launching your program, causing you to launch an older build. That build may have had an error with a line number in the *old* source code which doesn't match the *newer* source code. Check the Problems view to make sure nothing prevented compilation and clean/rebuild your project if you run into weird stuff.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens, thanks.
Sorry again for taking your time on this non-code-related topic.